# Can not receive proper parameters in my WCF service (jQuery, ajax)

Tags: ajax, wcf, jquery, parameters

I have a method on my client side. And I pass **"{'id':'1'}"** as data and I got a small problem with double quotes **"{"id":"1"}"**):[image]

But on server I got zero:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

and attributes for WCF method:
[image]

Comment: what data are sent to server? check it on your console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you add doublequotes to parameters? They must be send as json. In your exaple you send a string without key! Parameters must be set as

```
parameters = {id: 1}
```

Then server correctly receives data.